# Redirect back to previous page with dynamic urls

Tags: php, mysql

Sorry for the newbie question but I can't figured it out.
When user login I store his data in sessions like this

```
 $_SESSION['user_id']   = $res['user_id'];
 $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
 $_SESSION['password'] = $password;  
 $_SESSION['level'] = $res['level'];
 $_SESSION['firstname'] = $res['firstname'];
 $_SESSION['lastname']  = $res['lastname'];
 $_SESSION['user_image']= $res['user_image'];
 $_SESSION['email']     = $res['email']; 
 header('Location: users/main.php');
```

On every page I've put `session_start()` and everything work just fine. 
There are some pages like:

```
http://example.com/users/page.php?user_id=1
```

When user open `page.php` he see table filled with data from mysql with buttons edit/delete. When he click on edit button of item 1 is opened page which get `if (isset($_GET['item_id'])){...`

```
http://example.com/users/page.php?item_id=1
```

Now how to redirect user back to `page.php?user_id=1` when he click button submit?
I've tried with this

```
header("Location: page.php?user_id=$user_id");
```

but it doesn't return since properly and URL become `http://example.com/users/page.php?user_id=`

Comment: Because `$user_id` isn't set try: `header("Location: page.php?user_id=".$_SESSION['user_id']);`

Comment: Oh, silly me... of course I should use `$_SESSION['user_id']` since I have it and passed with `session_start()`. This is working perfectly. Thank's!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$user_id is not defined, so first defined it.

**instead of**

```
header("Location: page.php?user_id=$user_id");
```

**Use below code**

```
$user_id=$_SESSION['user_id']l
header("Location: /page.php?user_id=$user_id");
```